# NHibernate 2.1.0.4000 doesn't seem to like batch insert

Tags: nhibernate, batch-file, insert

I am using NHibernate 2.1.0.4000 in one of the projects. I have set **adonet.batch_size** to **100** in the cfg file however I still see that insert statement is treated as single statement. Update seems to work fine. What's going on?

Updated:
Is it because I've chosen identity as the primary key generator?

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" unsaved-value="0" type="Int32">
  <generator class ="identity"></generator>
</id>
```

Comment: I found this (http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/d4c8fd9625ef5f32/55c7a8db66f62a39?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=batch_size&pli=1) but not sure what it means.

Comment: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html: *Chapter 13. Batch processing*: "Note that NHibernate disables insert batching at the ADO level transparently if you use an identiy identifier generator."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know of any issues with that particular NHibernate version.

Are your using `native` as the ID generator for your entities? Because this will force every insert to happen alone, selecting back the generated ID. This is because the database needs to generate every ID. This would also explain why batching seems to work on updates.

If possible, you should switch to e.g. the `hilo` strategy, or even `guid` if you don't care about (easily) readable IDs.

Fabio has han interesting post [here](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/02/nh210-generators-behavior-explained.html) regarding this topic.

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server 2005 identity (generated int) as primary key. This explains why. thank you.

Comment: I am working with existing database so it's not quite possible to change the id.

Comment: Identity generators explained
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/02/nh210-generators-behavior-explained.html